# Ionic Creator - Reorder list items persisting in firebase?

Tags: javascript, firebase, ionic-framework, firebase-realtime-database

folks. This is my first time asking a question like this, so I’m hoping I can provide as much info as I can, but if there’s something confusing, please let me know and I’ll try to clarify it.

I’m using Ionic Creator to create a todo list of sorts using firebase and right now, I’m trying to implement a reorder function. I’ve been able to reorder the items with no issue, but the new reordered list never seems to save the new order or persist. I understand, after looking into it, that I need to find a way to make the reordered items persist in storage, but I’m not quite sure how.

Also, after doing some research, both on here and elsewhere, I think I need to store the index position of the item in firebase and then I can sort it by that index? I'm not entirely quite sure how to do that, even after looking here, so any insight helps.

I’ll post some code below and I hope it helps provide some insight. Again, this is my first time asking a question like this, so if there’s something obvious I’m missing, I would appreciate the feedback.

If it may also help, I followed these guides for reference for creating my app, if that may assist with providing any insight at all.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IrwrZBBOiP8
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IrwrZBBOiP8

Main home page:

```
          function ($scope, $stateParams, Todos, $ionicModal) {

$scope.showReorder = false;

$scope.toggle = function(v){
    $scope[v] = !$scope[v];
}

$scope.reorder = function(item, fromIndex, toIndex){
    $scope.items.splice(fromIndex, 1);
    $scope.items.splice(toIndex, 0, item);
}

$scope.items = Todos.items;


$scope.data = {
    'title': ''
}

$scope.modal = $ionicModal.fromTemplate("<ion-modal-view>" +
"<ion-header-bar class='bar-balanced'>" +
  "<h1 class='title'>Add a Movie Title</h1>" +
  '<button class="button button-clear" ng-click="closeModal()">Close</button>' +
"</ion-header-bar>" +
"<ion-content class='padding'>" +
  "<label class='item item-input'><input type='text' placeholder='Title' ng-model='data.title' /></label>" +
  "<button ng-click='addItem()' class='button button-balanced button-block'>Submit</button>" +
"</ion-content>" +  "</ion-modal-view>", {
    scope: $scope,
    animation: 'slide-in-up'
})

$scope.showModal = function(){
    $scope.modal.show();
}

$scope.closeModal = function(){
    $scope.data.title = '';
    $scope.modal.hide();
}

$scope.addItem = function(){
    Todos.addItem($scope.data.title);
    $scope.closeModal();   
} }
```

todos.js

```
angular.module('todos', ['firebase'])
.run(function(){
var config = {
    apiKey: (removed for posting purposes)
    authDomain: (removed for posting purposes)
    databaseURL: (removed for posting purposes)
    storageBucket: (removed for posting purposes)
  };
  firebase.initializeApp(config);
})

.service('Todos', ['$firebaseArray', function($firebaseArray){

var ref = firebase.database().ref().child('todos');
var items = $firebaseArray(ref);

var todos = {
    'items': items,
    addItem: function(title){
        items.$add({
            'title': title,
            'finished': false
        });
    },
    setFinished: function(item, newV){
        item.finished = newV;
        items.$save(item);
    }
}

return todos;

}]);
```